# TFS Nuget Packager build step included the code(*.cs) files in the nupkg file

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

In TFS, I added a step "Nuget Packager". The project builds fine but when I unzip the nupkg file, it contains the project files (*.csproj,*.cs, *.config files). I expect only binary files (e.g bin\Release*.dll files). What did I miss in the build definition?

Comment: Can you share the detailed settings for "Nuget Packager" task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Suggest you use the `.csproj`  instead of  `**\*.nuspec`  in *Path to csproj or nuspec file(s) to pack*  of **Pack NuGet task** .  This will get the same result in TFS as local.

With auto creating  `.nuspec` package manifest by nuget spec command. The XML manifest  file looks like：

```
  <metadata>
    <id>C:\Users\xx\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\TestNuGetPackager\TestNuGetPackager\xx.csproj</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>xxx</authors>
    <owners>xxx</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="SampleDependency" version="1.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

You need to **manually change the value of the `.nuspec` file** such as below including detail dlls in  and hardcode some info

```
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>TestNuGetPackager</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Test</authors>
    <owners>Test</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="bin\Release\TestNuGetPackager.dll" target="lib\46"/>
    </files>
</package>
```

After this you will get the only binary files, otherwise using the system auto generated `.nuspec` file, you will pack including the project files. Need to check in the modified `.nuspec` file to TFS and trigger the build again.

More details about how to use .nuspec file please refer this tutorial: [The role and structure of the .nuspec file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#the-role-and-structure-of-the-nuspec-file)

Comment: I originally had that but it did not help

Comment: @alltej You could packager the `**\*.nuspec` file instead `.csproj` file.  With creating a .nuspec package manifest. The manifest is an XML file that **describes the package's contents** and is itself included in the package. More details about how to use .nuspec file please refer this tutorial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#the-role-and-structure-of-the-nuspec-file

Comment: Yes, I did use the nuspec file. It was created using the `nuget spec` in the same directory as the *.csproj file.

Comment: @alltej  What's the result if you manually use nuget command to package and unzip the nupkg. This seems not related to TFS, there is no additional  settings in TFS build definition. If got the same result, you need to custom the .nuspec file instead of using the default `.nuspec` file. Since NuGet automatically includes all files when the package is created.

Comment: That's the one that really bothered me because when I use the `nuget pack` command locally, it only includes the binaries (DLLs and metadata). In the TFS build log, I saw the `nuget pack...` executed, so it uses the same command. So I thought, there might be some missing parameters in my build definition.

Comment: @alltej Double check if you specify the **configuration** as `Release` in your **Visual Studio Build task**  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/visual-studio-build https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/visual-studio-build#arguments

Comment: I have 3 steps for this definition: 1. Nuget Installer 2. Visual Studio Build 3. Nuget Packager. Yes, configuration is already set to release. I have MSBuild argument: /p:OutputPath=bin\Release

Comment: @alltej After some tests in my side. Looks like you are using  `.nuspec` file instead of `.csproj` file in your nuget pack task. However, with using the auto creating  .nuspec package manifest by nuget spec command in TFS. It will pack project files. You need to manually modify the `.nuspec` file to include the dlls. Another way is directly using `.csproj`, details please see my update answer.

Comment: So I change the nuget pack task to use the `.csproj` file. Now it is packaging the dlls only. So looks like the TFS nuget pack (using `.nuspec`) is not same behavior as local nuget pack  (using `.nuspec`). Also with TFS nuget pack task using the `.csproj`, it uses the values in `.nuspec` like the version. I was expecting that since it uses the `.csproj` it will read the values from the `AssemblyInfo.cs`